# What is the location of flag icons for Input method on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos

I was referring to this icon on the menubar:

[image]

Comment: One possible location would be in the same binary files as the keyboard layouts in /System/Library/Keyboard Layouts/AppleKeyboardLayouts.bundle/Contents/Resources/.

Comment: @LauriRanta i just take a look at that location, there's two .dat files and a bunch of folder with one single file InfoPlist.strings in it. I don't know how to extract the resource from those two .dat files though. any idea?

Comment: @TuanAnhTran See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/147820/how-to-extract-keyboard-layout-icon which uses the python script `apple-kbd-dat-icon-extract.py` from https://github.com/phible/scripts