# How to add icons for Keyboard Input switcher in MacOS

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-layout, icons

The British - Microsoft keyboard layout on MacOS has no icon/flag associated with it, so when using this layout with my Windows keyboard I either have to display the full text of the input name, or have an empty space where the icon should be.

Here's a screen shot showing an icon in the space:

[image: MacOS keyboard input switcher icon]

I'd like to fix it with my own icon (probably a Windows logo over a Union Jack). How can I do this?

Related but not the same as [What is the location of flag icons for Input method on Mac OS X?](https://superuser.com/q/439218/24368) which covers the location, which may or may not be some dat files. I borrowed the image above from that question.

Comment: Perhaps the patcher linked in that relevant question can be re-configured to your needs? Did you download it to see what's possible?

Comment: The patcher is all in Chinese, but appears to just replace the American flag with an old version. I don't really want to use an unknown binary to patch system files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the issue by following instructions at https://saltesta.com/hack/customizing-mac-input-source-icon/

In summary these are:

1. Create an [ICNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Icon_Image_format) file of the correct dimensions (16x16,32x32,48x48 etc) from an image you want to use. I used  https://anyconv.com/png-to-icns-converter/ to convert a PNG I created to ICNS. If you don't make the image a square, the conversion doesn't work.
2. Use [Ukulele](https://software.sil.org/ukelele/) to create a new Input Source from an existing one, and use the ICNS file.
3. Save the .bundle file to `~/Library/Keyboard Layouts/`
4. Run `open ~/Library/Keyboard\ Layouts/`
5. Restart your Mac

You can then have an Input Source with an icon you like.